# Problem with solving Cauchy problems of ODE systems numerically using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I have to solve numerically several systems of ordinary differential equations. I use Python for this (Numpy, Scipy). My problem is that I have to use the solution of the first ODE system in the next ODE system. I have modeled this situation using simpler examples that I present here. (Actually I have many multidimensional ODE systems, it is my scientific project.) Suppose I have to solve an ODE system

```
dx/dt = 2*x+y,
dy/dt = 3*x-y
```

with initial conditions

```
x(0)=1, y(0)=-1.
```

Further, I have to solve another ODE system

```
du/dt = u+2*v-u*x,
dv/dt = 2*u-v+4*v*y
```

with initial conditions

```
u(0)=-2, v(0)=3.
```

Here is my code (without importing required libraries at the very beginning). I work in Jupiter Notebook. I use the designations x1, x2, u1, u2 instead of x, y, u, v.

```
T = 100.
N_time = 1000

T_eval = np.asarray([i*T/N_time for i in range(N_time+1)])

def sys(t, X_state):
    x1 = X_state[0]
    x2 = X_state[1]
    dx1_dt = 2*x1+x2
    dx2_dt = 3*x1-x2
    dX_state_dt = np.asarray([dx1_dt, dx2_dt])
    return dX_state_dt

X_state0 = [1, -1]

sol = solve_ivp(fun=sys, t_span=[0, T], y0=X_state0, t_eval=T_eval)

x1 = sol.y[0, :]
x2 = sol.y[1, :]

def sys1(t, X_state_1):
    u1 = X_state_1[0]
    u2 = X_state_1[1]
    du1_dt = u1+2*u2-u1*x1
    du2_dt = 2*u1-u2+4*u2*x2
    dX_state_dt_1 = np.asarray([du1_dt, du2_dt])
    return dX_state_dt_1

X_state_1_0 = [-2, 3]

sol1 = solve_ivp(fun=sys1, t_span=[0, T], y0=X_state_1_0, t_eval=T_eval)
```

The program reports the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1001) (2,)"

I have written also another code for the second ODE system:

```
def sys1(t, X_state_1):
    u1 = X_state_1[0]
    u2 = X_state_1[1]
    du1_dt = u1+2*u2-np.multiply(u1, x1)
    du2_dt = 2*u1-u2+4*np.multiply(u2, x2)
    dX_state_dt_1 = np.asarray([du1_dt, du2_dt])
    return dX_state_dt_1
```

And the program reports the same error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1001) (2,)"

Comment: Why not write it as one large ODE system and solve one system?

Comment: Also read up on the "dense output" option to get the current values of x1,x2.